# Figure out the animal through a set of pictures

Tags: knowledge, visual, animals

***Which animal is related to this image?***

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The related animal is a:

> **CROW**

Because the three visual clues indicate...

> ...the partial names (or plots) of three movies from the given years with 'MURDER' in the title:
>
>  *[Dial M for Murder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dial_M_for_Murder)* (1954)
>  (Telephone → DIAL, 1000 in Roman numerals is 'M')
>
>  *[Anatomy of a Murder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomy_of_a_Murder)* (1959)
>  (An anatomical diagram)
>
>  *[Murder on the Orient Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_on_the_Orient_Express_(1974_film))* (1974)
>  (Plot involves a train and the *Belgian* detective, Hercule Poirot)
>
>  And the animal whose collective noun is a '[murder](https://www.birdspot.co.uk/bird-brain/why-is-a-group-of-crows-called-a-murder)' is a **CROW**!

Comment: "The collective noun of crow is murder"? Please explain. I can't understand this sentence at all.

Comment: @AlainReve See the link in that sentence for an explanation. A 'collective noun' is the word used for a particular group of something (often animals), e.g. a *herd* of cows, a *flock* of sheep...